# MongoDB Scala - scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Vector

Tags: mongodb, scala, vector, mapping, case-class

I'm using Scala Mongo Driver with Case-Class Codecs mappings according to its documentation such as:

```
object CodecProviders {
  lazy val codecRegistry = fromRegistries( fromProviders(
    classOf[User],
// ... other case classes
  ), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )
}
```

After changing one of my case classes to use `Vector` instead of `Seq` I started getting some errors related to Codec mappings:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
>   cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Vector

the `case class` looks like:

```
case class MyCaseClass(metadata: Metadata, data: Vector[Item])
```

There is nothing special about the `case class`. The main reason for switching to `Vector` is due performance benefits (constant access time for `index` based access), other case classes after changing to `Vector` works fine, I just happen to get this exception once in a while with this specific class, so I had to change it back to `Seq`.

What could be causing this exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `Seq` before, you probably have `List` instances inside your DB.

After chaning your `data` field to `Vector` however, the driver reads from the DB as a `List` (`$colon$colon` is the `::` from `List`) and tries to cast it to a `Vector` which is not possible.

You could change `data` to `List` instead or you would have to work around the issue that the mongo driver tries to read it as one.